# kafka exporter : query to get the current number of consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, grafana, kafka-consumer-api

I am implementing a kafka solution with consumer group autoscale capabilities, and I am using Grafana dashboards to display kafka exporter metrics such as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Can you please hint on  what prometheus/Grafana query should I run to display the current number of consumers for a specific consumer group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use kafka_consumergroup_members from the [kafka_exporter](https://github.com/danielqsj/kafka_exporter) :-  Amount of members in a consumer group metric

[image]

Update:-

Adding prometheus screenshot and the image used.

[image]

Command used:-

```
docker run -ti --network=host --rm -p 9308:9308 danielqsj/kafka-exporter --kafka.server=<kafka_server>
```

Comment: Are you sure  kafka_exporter has the metric kafka_consumergroup_members, it is not listed in the documentation of kafka_exporter, neither it is dispalyed on my prometheus metrics..

Comment: The doc seems to missing this metric. But I have tested this setup as of yesterday, hence the screenshot of :9308/metrics above. I have used the latest image though. That would explain the outdated doc. can you try this once with the updated image? 

`docker run -ti --network=host --rm -p 9308:9308 danielqsj/kafka-exporter --kafka.server=<kafka_server>`